# How many moderator positions are open?

Tags: discussion, election

I think this will be explicitly stated at a later stage in the election cycle, but....

1. How many moderator positions are open for this round of elections?
2. Is a moderator stepping down or is another moderator being added to the team?

---

I'm **definitely not** looking for any mud slinging about whether a moderator is stepping down or should be stepping down.

Comment: This is answered very clearly on the [election post](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1)... in the right sidebar... it says there are two positions.

Comment: the mods have said in chat that no one is currently stepping down. this is to augment the current staff.

Comment: closely related: I asked in the Election Chat Room how the CMs decided when and how many moderators get elected, see [the transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26937122#26937122) but the short answer is "when the existing mods feel like they might need help."

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - Keen has been kind enough to confirm [the reason why;](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27068382#27068382). Since I 'resigned' the flag-handling time has doubled.

Answer (score 4):

[Catija](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41668/catija) pointed out in a comment that I clearly overlooked that there are two open positions:

> This is answered very clearly on the [election post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1)... in the right sidebar... it says there are two positions.

[phantom42](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5184/phantom42) pointed out in a comment that:

> the mods have said in chat that no one is currently stepping down. this is to augment the current staff.

Answer (score 3):

There are presently 10 candidates standing for 2 vacant moderator positions

[image]

Given that the addition of one more candidate would allow us to move to [a primary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work) (and a further 4 days for the wider community to become involved in the election process) I hope **at least one more candidate** will choose to step up to the mark.

Comment: @Richard I don't follow your reasoning. Why do you think it would be a good thing to have a primary?

Comment: @mikeedenfield - It would seem largely academic anyway. No-one else is interested in standing...

Comment: @mikeedenfield - Pfft. Who needs that hassle?